# Количество различных элементов в массиве оптимально (c++)

Tags: c++, c, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив a с n неотрицательными целыми числами. Нужно определить количество различных чисел. В задаче 10^5 элементов и нужно управиться за 2 секунды , то есть обычные N^2 методы не получатся (пробовал). Придумал следующую идею: взять элемент и положить слева все меньшие его элементы, а все бОльшие элементы направо. Равные ему элементы соберем в кучу, после чего рекурсия. В общем, код выглядит так:

```
    int dist(int* a, int n, int first, int last)
{
    if (first >= last) { 
        if (first == last) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }
    else {
        int x = first, y = first;
        for (int i = first + 1; i <= last; i++)
        {
            if (a[x] > a[i]) {
                int t = a[i];
                for (int j = i; j > x; j--)
                {
                    a[j] = a[j - 1];
                }
                a[x] = t;
            }
            else if (a[x] == a[i])
            {
                for (int j = i; j > y; j--)
                {
                    a[j] = a[j - 1];
                }
                y++;
            }
        }
            return 1 + dist(a, n, first, x - 1) + dist(a, n, y + 1, last);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при некотором вводе, получаю неправильный ответ, значит в коде где-то прорех. Где именно тут ошибка?

Comment: Ну, т.е. вы решили изобрести быструю сортировку? :) Если ваш массив можно менять - сортировка + проход. Если это C++ - `sort` + `unique`. Поскольку язык не указан, код не пишу...

Comment: для справки. быстрая сортировка (а это она и есть по сути) имеет не совсем логарифмическую сложность. Я бы вообще советовал ей не пользоваться. Сортировка слиянием надёжнее.

Answer (score 4):

Вот на C++, с массивом в качестве контейнера:

```
const int N = 100000;

int main()
{
    int * a = new int[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = rand();

    cout << "Unique elements: " << (sort(a,a+N), unique(a,a+N)-a) << endl;

    delete[] a;
}
```

См. [тут](https://ideone.com/3KSxut).